# Form not 'POST'ing with a FormMethod.Post attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a form in a view like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDTActionBasedOnSelectedMetaAction", "TestCase", FormMethod.Post))
```

And an action method with the following signature:

```
[AcceptVerbs( new string[]{"GET","POST"})]
public void CreateDTActionBasedOnSelectedMetaAction(FormCollection fc)
```

However, when the 'submit' button (located in the form) is clicked, it comes to the action method, but the Request.HttpMethod property shows a "GET", and obviously the form data is then not available in the FormCollection object as it wasn't posted.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:part of the View:**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDTActionBasedOnSelectedMetaAction", "TestCase",  FormMethod.Post)){
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Test Case</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        <p>@DTContext.CurrentTestCase.Name</p>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Criteria)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Criteria)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DTTestCaseReqSet.DTMetaReqProcessor.DTMetaActions)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBox("MyListBox", new SelectList(Model.DTTestCaseReqSet.DTMetaReqProcessor.DTMetaActions.Where(p => p.Enabled == true), "NameWithID", "NameWithID"));

        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Select" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**UPDATE2**:
Okay that was silly. Turns out that the app has a custom routing system written by another dev, which expected a certain parameter in the query string to be preserved, which my code wasn't doing. This resulted in the routing system taking the POST from the form, being unable to find a suitable method, it converted it to a GET, which then found my actionmethod.

I would request this question to be deleted.

Comment: What kind of submit trigger are you using?  a submit button?  Post the code.

Comment: Can you post the full view please (i.e. where the placement of the button is)

Comment: What happens if you remove the GET verb from the action? Is it still invoked?

Comment: p.s. why would you have GET verb on a method that should only be dealing with POST?

Comment: I've tried removing all the decorators. It still hits, but my problem is that the form does not post, even though FormMethod.Post is set

Comment: going to have to see more code here... what does the actual html look like after it's been requested? Are you using any ajax or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Create two action methods.  One for get and one for post.

```
[HttpPost]
public void CreateDTActionBasedOnSelectedMetaAction(FormCollection fc)

[HttpGet]
public void CreateDTActionBasedOnSelectedMetaAction()
```

Comment: That's fine but the Post is never hit, as in, the form doesn't post even with the FormMethod.Post set on it.

Comment: instead of using the form collection.  Can you switch it to your model?